# how to handle moving/rearranging cells in a tableView with core data

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to find a code sample that shows how to handle moving/rearranging cells in a tableView with core data.  I can move elimenty array. How do I update Core data (Mybase)?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription* entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Mybase"
                                                     inManagedObjectContext:self.objectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entityDescription];

empArray = [(NSArray*)[self.objectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];

Mybase *employee = [empArray objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];

[empArray removeObject: employee];
[empArray insertObject: employee atIndex:toIndexPath.row]
}
```

Comment: core date or core data? it's hard to understand what you are asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a unique id for each entry in Core data. When you make any modifications on any object, say move the object or just update the content, you just save the core data instance with the updated data using that unique id. No need to remove it and insert it again. Simply call 'save' and it will do the rest.

For example, the value corresponding to row 2 was 'AAA', the unique id for the same being 2( set by you or as is got from the server)
Now you want to change the value corresponding to row 2 to 'AA', link that to the unique id(in this case 2) and then save it.

Answer (score 0):

I added a id to track the position for each Attribute in Core Data. In this example, I called it "positionInTable". Moreover, I used a for loop to update these values, always when a cell gets moved.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        let movedObject = self.itemArray[sourceIndexPath.row]
        itemArray.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
        itemArray.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)

        var positionStart = 0

        for item in itemArray {
            item.positionInTable = Int32(positionStart)
            positionStart += 1
        }

        saveData()
    }
```

Moreover, I just added a sortDescriptior in the load function. Everything works in my code so far.

```
// Add this to your fetch request
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "positionInTable", ascending: true)]
```